# Delete rows returned by select?

Tags: postgresql

I have a simple query that inner joins:

```
select *
    from driver d
    inner join car c on c.id = d.car_id where c.dealership_id=${did} and d.id=${driverId}
```

This returns the drivers I care about.

I want to delete any driver row returned by that query.

I tried:

```
delete from driver
where exists (
   select *
        from driver d
        inner join car c on c.id = d.car_id where c.dealership_id=${did} and d.id=${driverId}
)
```

but that deleted all drivers in the drivers table.

How do I delete only the drivers returned by the select statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `where id in` instead of `exists` will work:

```
delete from driver
where id in (
   select id
        from driver d
        inner join car c on c.id = d.car_id 
        where c.dealership_id=${did} and d.id=${driverId}
    )
```